# What is the opposite of "Racist"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I cannot find the term. Does one exist? ex. He is a racist! No, he is a (word that means the opposite of racist).

Comment: What would the term mean? _Racist_ is not a term on an obvious spectrum.

Comment: An *equal-opportunity misanthrope*.

Comment: Questions about opposites and antonyms ought to be banned altogether. The questioners never have any idea what they're asking for.

Comment: Hi NateIV: Would you please edit the question to comply with our requirements for this type of question, which we call [tag:single-word-requests]? We want you to at least check a thesaurus for antonyms of the specified word; tell us which one you checked and why its best suggestions do not work for you, and finally, include a sentence that matches the sort of context you want to use it in. Also, @JohnLawler if you feel that way, why didn't you vote to close? The question currently doesn't comply with our standards, and there are applicable reasons to put the question on hold for improvement.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. *Racist* has many different axes. The "opposite" could be someone who loves other races, or believes other races than his own are superior, or does not believe race is relevant, or does not believe race exists in the first place, or hates other races but has no power against them, or hates other races but takes no action against them, etc. etc. Please [edit] your post to provide additional context.

Comment: I agree with others, 'opposite' does not work alone.  You must also try to describe what else you'd like to connote.  FWIW 'the meaning of 'racist' is sort of blurred today too ... seems any 'bias' whatsover, intentional or not qualifies .. it use to mean something more like purposeful directed hatred and actively seeking to undermine etc... not merely stereotyping or favortism

Comment: The opposite of any word in the English language is "NOT [word]". The opposite of "blue" is "not blue". The opposite of "the" is "not the". The opposite of opossum is "not opossum". The opposite of "up" is "not up". The opposite of "to" is "not to". The opposite of interesting is "not interesting". The opposite of "well researched" is "not well researched". And so forth. So the opposite of "racist" is "not racist" (and the opposite of "a racist" is "not a racist"). I feel like we need a canonical question on this.

Comment: Xenophile, obviously.

Comment: @JohnLawler yes, it's often unclear whether they want *sober*, or *knurd*, as the antonym of *drunk*.

Comment: This question is fairly simple, and could easily be looked up. Just go to almost any online dictionary, type in racist, and look at the list of antonyms.

Answer (score 2):

> anti-racist. 
>   UK   US
>   opposed to the unfair treatment of people who belong to other races:
>   *anti-racist legislation.*
>
> **anti-racist.** 
>   UK   US
>   an anti-racist person.
>   — [Cambridge Advanced Learner’s Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/anti-racist)

Comment: *Anti-racist* is not an objective description; it is a self-awarded accolade which does not in fact exclude racist views, so long as it is one of the approved varieties of racism.

Comment: @TimLymington that seems abut strong! Is it any more subjective that racist? And "self-awarded" .. surely that depends on usage

Answer (score 1):

Impartial might work. Impartial means

> > adjective
> >     1.
> >     not partial or biased; fair; just

Equitable also would make sense in this content.

> > characterized by equity or fairness; just and right; fair; reasonable

These definitions are from http://www.dictionary.com/browse/impartial

Answer (score 1):

"Xenophile," is the word you are looking for as a term for someone who loves foreign cultures or other ethnicities.

Comment: Really good answer because the opposite of such a strongly negative word ought to carry a strong positive meaning as this word does. Welcome to English.StackExchange @Nick; please edit your answer to include a standard dictionary definition (extract) and also the link to that page  such as https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/xenophile

Answer (score 1):

The word **non-racist** is defined as

> not influenced by a person's race

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/non-racist

So this qualifies as an antonym of 'racist', although the exact opposite of such a strongly negative word really ought to carry a strong positive meaning as [xenophile](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/430965/231519) suggested by @Nick does. Anothet positive word that connotes the opposite idea of racism is **egalitarian** which can be used as adjective or noun, and is defined as
​

> believing that all people are equally important and should have the same rights and opportunities in life

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/egalitarian

Answer (score 0):

A fairly contemporary, idiomatic form is not one word, but two: ***colour-blind*** (may or may not need the hyphen, depending on your local customs).